# BCL Immutable Collections: equality is non-symmetric

Tags: c#, data-structures, immutability, base-class-library, immutable-collections

Since immutable data strucutures are first-class values we can compare them for equality or order as we do with any other values. But things became complicated in BCL immutable collections preview because every immutable collection can be parameterized by `IEqualityComparer<T>`/`IComparer<T>` instances. Looks like immutable collections with different comparers should not be allowed to compare (since equality is not defined for comparers itself), because it makes equality relation non-symmetric:

```
var xs = ImmutableList<string>.Empty.Add("AAA")
  .WithComparer(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

var ys = ImmutableList<string>.Empty.Add("aaa")
  .WithComparer(StringComparer.Ordinal);

Console.WriteLine(xs.Equals(ys)); // true
Console.WriteLine(ys.Equals(xs)); // false
```

Will this behavior be fixed somehow?

Comment: Since they have different equality, how would you propose to fix it? it kinda makes sense that it uses the comparer of the first operand - I'm not sure I could call it a bug...

Comment: This strikes me as hard to fix.  It is a CTP.  The only way this is going to be addressed at all is when you provide feedback through the designated feedback channel for the CTP.  There's a link in the blog post, "call for feedback section".  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx

Comment: I tend to agree with Marc on his reasoning.

Comment: Mark, non-symmetric equality relation makes no sens for me. Possible fix - remove `Equals` override (use reference equality) and provide explicit methods for lhs/rhs collection equality.

Comment: @MarcGravell It's a bug, since it violates the [contract of `Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) which requires symmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equality is a difficult thing to define, and even more difficult to achieve consensus on that definition in a room of smart engineers. :)
We're actually going to be *removing* value-equality from the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of the immutable collections so that these methods provide the same speed (and near uselessness) as most other types in the BCL and in customer code.

We do very much hope to add value-equality methods to the immutable collections in a future release.

Comment: Did value-equality for immutable collections ever make any progress? Or was it definitively rejected? With records now in C# 9, it would make functional domains much easier to express. A seemingly natural (and probably wrong, given the engineering talent that's already thought about this) resolution to the OP issue is to also require equality of comparers for two collections to be equal. What's the flaw in that approach?

Comment: Yes, it was definitely rejected. That doesn't prevent folks from implementing their own equality comparers for collections and using them in order to achieve by-value equality, however.